# List from async Task in sync MainPage

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm really looking for the solution and can't find proper instruction.
I have async method in RestService.cs

```
 public async static Task<List<Convert>> CheckBTCUSDAsync()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string restUrl = 
    "https://bitbay.net/API/Public/BTCUSD/trades.json";
            HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await 
    client.GetAsync(restUrl);
            if (responseGet.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var response = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                List<Convert> currencies = Convert.FromJson(response);
                //Debug.WriteLine(currencies[0].Date);
                return currencies;
            }
            else
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine("***************");
                //Debug.WriteLine("*****FALSE*****");
                //Debug.WriteLine("***************");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I want to use it in my MainPage but of course I cant use await in sync method. I found that some devs suggest putting async tasks in eg OnStart method: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-async-task-startup/
I need to to Bind the returned list to picker in Xaml but of course when trying to use:

```
var convert = RestService.CheckBTCUSDAsync().Result;
```

It hangs the UI thread. Anyone knows what is the best/easiest way to resolve this?

Comment: why not call it from OnAppearing?  var convert = await RestService.CheckBTCUSDAsync();

Comment: @Jason I will read about OnAppearing(), thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got it to work on my app

```
var convert = Task.Run(() => RestService.CheckBTCUSDAsync()).Result;
```

Comment: great, it worked for me also :) I've tried similar construction in different async method but didn't know it'll work in sync method:) thanks a lot